# gitlab push to master jenkins trigger

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have jenkins and gitlab set up and working. I am using gitlab as the version control system for our puppet environment. What I would like to achieve is when I push changes from a git client to the master branch in gitlab, Jenkins will push that commit to multiple puppet servers. The commits I would like to pull are the puppet manifests.

I have a project set up in gitlab with a http URL. I have set up a job in Jenkins accordingly. In the Repository URL, I have entered the http URL to my repo in gitlab. However it is prompting me to add my subversion credentials.

```
 Username/password authentication
 SSH public key authentication (svn+ssh)
 HTTPS client certificate.
```

I would like to use SSH public key auth. However it is asking for the following:

```
 User name  
 Pass phrase    
 Private key
```

What details do I need to put here and on what server? Should this be a user on my gitlab server which has access to the http URL?

Thanks - Oli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was approaching this wrong. I installed the gitlab jenkins plugin and entered the git URL and a Gitpoll schedule and set up a build job and it all started to work

Here's my blog on it...

http://devsops.blogspot.com/2013/01/gitlab-jenkins-and-puppet-playing.html